# Configure FireFox to stream .wmv

Tags: firefox, nginx, video-streaming, windows-media-player, wmv

Problem: FireFox waits untill download completes before opening windows media player.

Desired outcome: When download starts open Windows Media player and stream video.

Currently Chrome and IE are performing as desired. Only FireFox waits for download to complete.  Not sure if this is a FF configuration issue or the headers being sent.

Server: NginxPlus

Headers:
        // Write Headers
        // stream the video via redirect

```
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Type:video/x-ms-wmv');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=gt.wmv');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $orlPath);
```

TIA

Comment: What is Firefox set to do on `Edit->Preferences->Applications->Windows Media Video`?

Comment: Use Windows Media Player (default)

Comment: I got it to work but not the desired way.   I used about:config and removed video/x-ms-wmv from plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types.  Now it displays in the browser window using VLC rather than opening up windows media player as a separate application (which is desired).  I can't expect users to update about:config.

Comment: Is using .wmv a requirement? Can't you switch to something like H264/AAC in a mp4 container that can be played directly in the majority of browsers/devices?

Comment: We are switching to .mp4 for existing library has many terabytes or .wmv's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your headers are alright, this seems to be the default Firefox behavior.

> Normally Mozilla-based browsers deal with multimedia files (for example, .wmv and .mpg files) by first downloading them, and then launching the media player.

Source: the 2007 [mozillaZine - Streaming Media](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Streaming_media) page.

There's no alternative that doesn't involve installing some third-party plugin client-side. These work by forwarding the URL to the external-player or by enabling the embedding of the source file (eg: [MediaElement.js + Silverlight](http://mediaelementjs.com/#devices)).

Comment: I was hoping that in the 8 years since that writing Mozilla would have a better solution.